# Is vaadin Java UI framework is supported by quarkus framework

Tags: vaadin, quarkus

I want to use the vaadin UI java framework in my quarkus framework, But I am unsuccessful in that. when I am loading any static resources(CSS, js, etc..) files it is not getting loaded And I guess not even default CSS is getting applied to the UI components, I am new to this framework, If anyone wants to suggest, please.
Here is the sample demo UI project which I am trying to implement.
[https://harshithpawarg@bitbucket.org/harshithpawarg/quarkus_vaadin.git][1]

run Command: $. mvn clean install && mvn compile quarkus:dev -pl ui

Answer (score 2):

Vaadin is working on an integration with Quarkus. The target version is Vaadin 22. They might already have something running on Vaadin 21.

The current work can be seen in the GitHub [repository of the extension](https://github.com/vaadin/quarkus) and the [repository of the project base](https://github.com/vaadin/base-starter-flow-quarkus/).

Update: Vaadin 22 is released as a non-LTS version and [integrates Quarkus](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/flow/integrations/quarkus).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Vaadin doesn't yet support Quarkus (see https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/5485).
However, experimental Quarkus extensions to use Vaadin with Quarkus are available [here](https://github.com/moewes/quarkus-vaadin-lab) and [here](https://github.com/Nano-Vaadin-Demos/nano-vaadin-quarkus).

Answer (score 1):

Why don’t you make a Quarkus backend and another Java project with Vaadin which communicates via Rest with the backend ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get Vaadin 14 (vaadin-demo-business-app) working as native image in production mode using the [quarkus-vaadin-lib](https://github.com/moewes/quarkus-vaadin-lab) example.
I did use the native-image-agent to generate the META-INF/native-image json files and added wildcard entries in resource-config.json

```
    {
        "resources":[
            {"pattern":"META-INF/VAADIN.*"},
            {"pattern":"META-INF/resources.*"},
```

Only dev mode is harder, when running in Quarkus the browser can't resolve the frontend through webpack:// and webpack-internal:// and I do not know how to achieve this.
But this can work as long as you can keep the modules using Vaadin compatible to run as normal war, and compile the end product into a Quarkus+GraalVM executable. Only you can't use Quarkus specific code in the web ui modules then which still makes it all a bit hacky.